# Facebook Open Graph not publishing to profiles which dont have timelines activated

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Steps:

Our app recently switched to using App Access Token for open graph.  Following is the URL using which the action is being published:

https://graph.facebook.com/FACEBOOKID/namespace:action

The publish works fine and id is being returned.  Also following url returns the app activity with the details of new activity that was created using URL above:

https://graph.facebook.com/FACEBOOKID/namespace:action?access_token=app_access_token

Problem:

Activity published is not visible on old Profiles that dont have timelines activated.  It used to work fine when access token was being used instead of app access token.  Switching profile to use timeline shows the activity though.

I have been googling to find if anyone else is facing the same issue but havent been able to find concrete answer.  Am i missing something in terms of app configuration or is this a known behavior? Thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Timeline will become mandatory for every user soon, so I wouldn’t worry about this much …